# WebStorm automatically goes to next line after commenting current line

Tags: comments, phpstorm, webstorm

I've a question about WebStorm: if I comment out a line my cursor jumps automatically to the next line.

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 5):

It can't be avoided. Please follow [IDEA-119435](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-119435) for updates